# Correctly creating CakePHP Model Associations with MongoDB

Tags: php, cakephp, models, mongodb

I'm busy testing Models with MongoDB. I have two Models: Recipe and 
Tag. 

`class Recipe extends AppModel { 
    var $name = 'Recipe'; 
        var $mongoSchema = array( 
                'name' => array('type' => 'string'), 
                'description' => array('type' => 'string'), 
                'tags' => array('type' => 'array'), //the tags "tag" value 
                'created' => array('type' => 'datetime'), 
                'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime'), 
        ); 
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( 
        'Tag' => 
            array( 
                'className'              => 'Tag', 
                'joinTable'              => 'recipe', 
                'foreignKey'             => '_id', 
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'tags', 
                'unique'                 => true, 
            ) 
    ); 
} 
class Tag extends AppModel { 
    var $name = 'Tag'; 
        var $mongoSchema = array( 
                'tag' => array('type' => 'string'), 
                'description' => array('type' => 'string'), 
                'created' => array('type' => 'datetime'), 
                'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime'), 
        ); 
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( 
        'Recipe' => 
            array( 
                'className'              => 'Recipe', 
                'joinTable'              => 'recipe', 
                'foreignKey'             => 'tags', 
                'associationForeignKey'  => '_id', 
                'unique'                 => true, 
            ) 
    ); 
}`

Recipe has many tags and vica versa, but how do I correctly represent 
this so that it maps correctly with MongoDB via CakePHP associations as the Model HABTM etc relay on traditional SQL relational data?

Futhermore, how do I ensure that the relationships are managed 
correctly when we either delete a recipe or delete a tag?

I suspect I will have to create a behavior to manage the relationships. I.E. a hasReference and isReferenced much like hasOne, hasAndBelongsToMany, etc.

Comment: It may be worth checking out https://github.com/lorenzo/MongoCake

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no MongoDB datasource, which handles model associations in a way you'd expect it in CakePHP. For one, NoSQL databases are conceptually not made for that, second, the CakePHP 1.x Model/Datasource architecture makes it very difficult to implement such diverse database technologies.

However, you might take a look at the [Lithium](http://lithify.me/) framework. They have implemented full "relational" support for MongoDB into their model architecture.